# Why does storing multiple tasks in a var first and awaiting them afterwards make a difference?

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

Given this code... Why will Main1() take ~ 1 second but Main2() only 500 ms?

Why does it make a difference to store the Task in a variable first and awaiting then?

```
async Task Main1()
{
    await DoStuff(1);
    await DoStuff(2);
}

async Task Main2()
{
    var t1 = DoStuff(1);
    var t2 = DoStuff(2);
    await t1;
    await t2;
}

async Task DoStuff(int number)
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: In Main1: DoStuff(1); wait until finished; DoStuff(2); Wait until finished. In Main2: DoStuff(1); DoStuff(2); Wait until finished 1 (while 2 runs in parallel); Wait until finished 2 (maybe already finished while waiting for 1

Comment: In `Main1()`, your code doesn't call `DoStuff(2)` until _after_ the first `await` completes. So the asynchronous operations represented by the calls to `DoStuff()` run one after another, instead of concurrently as in `Main2()`. See duplicate.

Comment: If `DoStuff(2)` does not need `DoStuff(1)` to have ended in order to work properly, your `Main2()` will run faster because both `t2` and `t1` will run in parallel. In `Main1()` they run in sequence.

Comment: By the way, I recommend also observing the difference that `Thread.Sleep(500)` vs `await Task.Delay(500)` makes. Try swapping them out in [this example](https://rextester.com/GBWBR33600). Note that `Thread.Sleep` here is a stand-in for CPU-bound work.

Answer (score 5):

It's not about whether you store the tasks in variables, it's about when you start the tasks. In this case:

```
async Task Main1()
{
    await DoStuff(1); // Task 1
    await DoStuff(2); // Task 2
}
```

You start task 2 *after you wait for task 1 to finish*. Note that calling `DoStuff` *starts the task*, and `await` *wait* for it to finish.

In this case:

```
async Task Main2()
{
    var t1 = DoStuff(1); // Task 1
    var t2 = DoStuff(2); // Task 2
    await t1;
    await t2;
}
```

You start task 2 without waiting for task 1 to finish, so they are executed at the same time. `DoStuff(2)` does not wait for `DoStuff(1)` to finish before running.

If you did this instead:

```
async Task Main3()
{
    var t1 = DoStuff(1);
    await t1;
    var t2 = DoStuff(2);
    await t2;
}
```

You would get the same behaviour as `Main1`. This shows that whether or not you put the task into variables doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

In Main1, `DoStuff(2)` get started only when `DoStuff(1)` is done.
But in Main2, both t1 and t2 task start almost at same time and are handled concurrently.